# Why is the first label on highcharts bar chart missing?

Tags: highcharts

[image: bar chart]

https://jsfiddle.net/rcvwsbdm/

```
var data = [{"name":"Adult Emergency","y":2},{"name":"Adult Social Care and Health","y":1},{"name":"Anaesthetics","y":1},{"name":"Audiology","y":2}];

var chart_options = {
  "chart":  { "type":"bar", "height":"700" },
  "xAxis":{ "categories":[""] },    
  "series":[{"data": data}]
  };

$('#main').highcharts(chart_options);
```

jQuery: 2.2.4
Highcharts: 4.4.2

Comment: Inside your options.categories you have empty string that is your first label. To avoid this situation use empty array instead: https://jsfiddle.net/rcvwsbdm/1/

Comment: Thankyou, please post an answer and I will accept!

Comment: Happy to read that my example worked for you. I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now inside your options.categories you have an empty string:

```
categories: ['']
```

This is the reason why you have first label as an empty string. To avoid this situation you can use an empty array instead:

```
categories: []
```

Here you can see an example how it can work:
https://jsfiddle.net/rcvwsbdm/1/

Best regards.